# Equal height columns on resize (WordPress)

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm using the following code which works very well for creating equal height columns on load but I am having issues getting it to work when a browser is resized or a device orientation is changed.

```js
//Set equal height columns
(function($) {
 if ($(window).width() > 414) {

        // Select and loop the container element of the elements you want to equalise
        $('#contact-dept').each(function(){  

          // Cache the highest
          var highestBox = 0;
          
          // Select and loop the elements you want to equalise
          $('.vc_col-sm-4', this).each(function(){

            // If this box is higher than the cached highest then store it
            if($(this).height() > highestBox) {
             highestBox = $(this).height(); 
            }
        });  
          
          // Set the height of all those children to whichever was highest 
          $('.vc_col-sm-4',this).height(highestBox);              
    }); //End Loop
  }; //End Media Query
})(jQuery);
```

Any suggestions on how I can trigger this to run on resize. I did try some variations of the jQuery .rezize() but could not get to work (I'm new to js).

Many thanks.

Comment: Any other suggestions woudl be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to solve this with CSS. Use display:table for the parent and display:table-cell for the columns. You no longer need the jQuery code and the browser will take care of the layout for you.

Comment: I've used in a few places so I don't want to have to alter all the code again but thanks.